# No attempt to answer, code-only answer with own library. Isn't that self-promotion in disguise?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908602/1244884) as spam.

The author doesn't even try to find the root cause of the bug. They could have suggested a solution with both technologies (OP's and theirs) and that would have been fine to me.

Instead they just posted a code-only answer. The educational value of that is low IMHO.

Why isn't that spam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That post **doesn't look like spam**. It doesn't even have a link. There's almost no chance that the moderator who sees your "spam" flag will have any clue why you flagged it as spam.

Reserve spam flags for *obvious*, *unarguable* spam.

In cases like this, where the user is promoting their own library in an answer to a question where it is of dubious applicability, please use a custom moderator flag instead, where you can explain that and give us more context.

Comment: Fair enough; will do that. Don't moderators carry out some due diligence first though? For example the link between the answer and the user is obvious if you looked at the user profile.

Comment: @customcommander Considering the amount of mods we've lost and the amount of flags that get raised I'm impressed they're even processed to be honest.

Comment: Well, yeah. Obviously the mod who handled the flag didn't see it in this case. It's a toss-up. Sometimes we do, sometimes we miss it. For example, when answering this question, I missed the fact that the answer was edited in-between the time your flag was raised and handled. The edit removed all the links, and made it look even *less* like an answer. There's an awful lot of stuff to remember to look at...

Comment: Does this mean that we should now edit in affiliation? It seems to be a new approach.

Comment: @Scratte Not new. You know that my approach has always been to preserve value whenever possible. This might be spam according to a restrictive definition, but at the same time, from what I can tell, it is also a useful, alternative solution to the problem. That means deleting it would be doing the community and the Internet a disservice. Since it can be salvaged and all problems avoided by adding attribution, I prefer to do that. Naturally, I'm not going to do it for blatantly inappropriate/inapplicable spam, or for someone who is a *chronic* spammer, blasting their nonsense everywhere.

Comment: Nothing wrong with flagging for moderator intervention if you want a mod to make the judgment call, especially using evidence only available to mods (like deleted answers by the same user, spamming the same thing). Don't take my decision to edit the disclaimer into this particular answer as evidence that you or anyone else should *always* do that, without involving a mod.

Comment: Personally, I would not edit in such thing. I would only ask the author to do it, and see what happens. Previously I'd been inclined to bring attention to a problem if they chose to not edit in the affiliation.

Comment: I rarely bother with asking the author to do things. If they were going to do it, they would have done it from the outset. Experience tells me that sort of advice is almost always ignored, which leaves the problematic content visible on the site. If I can fix it myself, and I think that doing so would preserve/add value, then I will. Otherwise, I'm just going to delete the post. It's the same thing as with typos. I'm not going to leave a comment suggesting for you to fix them when I can just edit and fix them myself. As I said, flagging for mod review is always a reasonable choice.

Comment: @customcommander: You should make the job of moderators as easy as possible. Anything *you* can do, you should do, including providing sufficient context (answering the "Why?") (even if it requires more work on your part). That includes not having to follow links 3 levels deep. Serve the information [on a silver platter](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+a+silver+platter). E.g. *"I suggest to do X because of A, B, and C. See reference K, L, and M"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Will do next time. Thanks for your feedback.